# Order of elements of the dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, dihedral-groups

Let $G= ${$e, r, r^2, . . . , r^{23}, s, sr, sr^2, . . . , sr^{23} $}  be the dihedral group with $48$ elements.

(a) Compute which elements of $G$ have order $3$.

(b) Determine if $H =$ {$r^i$ with $i$ even, $sr^j$ with $j$ odd} is a subgroup  of $G$. Hint: perform the required calculations with types of element $sr^l$ and $sr^l$.

(a) We know that if H is a subgroup of G then $|H|\mid|G|$

From this, we get that the elements of order 3  are $r^8$ and $r^{16}$

since $(r^8)^3 = r^{24}  =1  \implies|r^8|=3 $

and $(r^{16})^3 = r^{48} =  r^{24} r^{24} =1 \implies |r^{16}|=3$

(b) $H=$ {$r^2,r^4,r^6,...,r^{22},sr^1,sr^3,sr^5,....sr^{23}$}

H is a subgroup of G if $H \ne \emptyset$ and for every $x,y \in H$ $ xy^{-1} \in G$.

Then since $H \ne \emptyset$ and $sr = r^{-1}s \in H$ it follows that H is a sungroup of G.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but you have to justify why elements of the form $sr^i$ are not of order $3$.

Comment: Can I just say that it is because for every i = 1,2,.... $(sr^i)^3 =sr^i \ne 1 $ Therefore $|sr^i| \ne 3$

Comment: I think that "since $H \ne \emptyset$ and $sr = r^{-1}s \in H$ it follows that H is a sungroup of G." is not sufficient justification. Also the definition you write of the H at the begining is not what you wrote below: you should be careful writting correctly the formulae or then one has to guess what you meant...

Comment: It is because I wrote wrong. $H= $ {$r^i$, i even ,$sr^j$ j odd}. What else I should say to prove that H is a subgroup?